# How to merge 2 SQL CASE statements for output in a single column

Tags: sql-server, merge, case

I'm using SQL Server 2014 and I have a query where I need to merge 2 CASE statements for output in a single column called, say, 'Market Final'.

Case statement 1 is as follows:

```
(CASE e.TravelAgencyTypeCode WHEN 'DMC' THEN g2.CountryGroup ELSE g.CountryGroup END) AS 'Market Final'
```

When I run my query with the CASE statement above, it runs fine and I get exactly what I was looking for. It gets a bit more complicated for me when I need to add the second CASE Statement which also affects the "Market Final" column.

CASE Statement 2 is as follows:

```
(CASE c.TAProfileID WHEN c.TAProfileID = '316' and c.CurrencyCode = 'MUR' THEN g.CountryGroup = 'DB Local' ELSE g.CountryGroup = 'DB International' END)
```

I've read that this can be done with the UNION ALL statement but I just can't figure out how to deal with it. I also have a feeling that my CASE Statement 2 is wrongly written.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: Here is my full SQL Query so that you get the whole picture:

```
USE  MyDatabase

SELECT 

  b.PropertyCode,
  c.PMSConfirmationNumber,   
  a.FirstName + ' ' + a.LastName AS 'Name',
  b.ReservationStatus AS 'Status',
  d.rsl_nationality AS 'Nationality',
  d.rsl_rateplan AS 'Rate Plan Code',
  d.rsl_roomtype AS 'Room Type',
  i.RoomType2 AS 'Room Type 2', 
  b.GuestCount AS 'Total Guest', 
  c.CurrencyCode,
  e.TravelAgencyTypeCode AS 'Source of Business',
  c.TAProfileID,
  e.Name AS 'Tour Operator', 
  g.CountryGroup AS 'Market', 
  c.TAProfileID2, 
  e2.Name AS 'Booking Origin (1)', 
  g2.CountryGroup AS 'Booking Origin (2)',

  (CASE e.TravelAgencyTypeCode WHEN 'DMC' THEN g2.CountryGroup ELSE  g.CountryGroup END) AS 'Market Final'

 FROM GuestNameInfo a
 JOIN GuestStaySummary b ON a.ReservationStayID = b.ReservationStayID
 LEFT JOIN ReservationStay c ON c.ReservationStayID = b.ReservationStayID
 LEFT JOIN P5RESERVATIONLIST d ON d.rsl_code = b.ReservationStayID 
 LEFT JOIN TravelAgency e ON e.TravelAgencyID = c.TAProfileID 
 LEFT JOIN Market g ON e.CountryCode = g.CountryCode 
 LEFT JOIN TravelAgency e2 ON e2.TravelAgencyID = c.TAProfileID2
 LEFT JOIN Market g2 ON e2.CountryCode = g2.CountryCode 
 LEFT JOIN Exrate h ON h.Ccode = c.CurrencyCode
 LEFT JOIN RoomCat i ON b.PropertyCode = i.Property AND d.rsl_roomtype = i.RoomType
```

So now I need to add the CASE 2 Statement 2 to this query so that the changes are reflected in the 'Market Final" column.

And here is the output I'm after:

```
PropertyCode....CurrencyCode SourceofBusiness TAProfileID.... Market .... Booking Origin (2)  MarketFinal
    A            MUR          DMC                 50           Other Mkt      Scandinavia       Scandinavia
    A            USD          TO                  75             UK             UK                UK
    B            USD          DIR                 316             DB             USA               DB International
    B            MUR          DIR                 316            DB             MTS               DB Local
```

Comment: In your second case, does the result really have to be g.CountryGroup = 'DB Local' ELSE g.CountryGroup = 'DB International'?

Comment: try (CASE WHEN c.TAProfileID = '316' and c.CurrencyCode = ...

Comment: We might need to see these CASEs in context.

Comment: @CurseStacker Yes it has to be like this.

Comment: If you edit the question and add an explanation of the intended logic, illustrate the logic by a dozen rows with sample data and simplified structure and what result you expect to get, I would be able to write you a proper answer with a query, that would be easy to verify. Otherwise you can look up what `CROSS APPLY` does and figure out how it can be useful in your case.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov Just updated my question with the full query in its context. Hope this might be of some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example and other information provided, you seem to want the following logic:

- if `e.TravelAgencyTypeCode = 'DMC'`, then return `g2.CountryGroup`
- otherwise:

  - if `c.TAProfileID = '316'`, then:

    - if `c.CurrencyCode = 'MUR'`, then return `'DB Local'`
    - otherwise return `'DB International'`
  - otherwise return `g.CountryGroup`

You could implement this logic more or less literally with nested CASEs, using either the simple CASE syntax:

```
CASE e.TravelAgencyTypeCode
  WHEN 'DMC' THEN g2.CountryGroup
  ELSE
    CASE c.TAProfileID
      WHEN '316' THEN
        CASE c.CurrencyCode
          WHEN 'MUR' THEN 'DB Local'
          ELSE 'DB International'
        END
      ELSE g.CountryGroup
    END
END
```

or the searched CASE syntax:

```
CASE
  WHEN e.TravelAgencyTypeCode = 'DMC' THEN g2.CountryGroup
  ELSE
    CASE
      WHEN c.TAProfileID = '316' THEN
        CASE
          WHEN c.CurrencyCode = 'MUR' THEN 'DB Local'
          ELSE 'DB International'
        END
      ELSE g.CountryGroup
    END
END
```

However, nested CASEs may not be too readable – particularly when you do not have many subcases, like in this situation. So, if I were you, I might actually flatten the above construct in this way:

```
CASE
  WHEN e.TravelAgencyTypeCode = 'DMC' THEN g2.CountryGroup
  WHEN c.TAProfileID = '316' AND c.CurrencyCode = 'MUR' THEN 'DB Local'
  WHEN c.TAProfileID = '316' THEN 'DB International'
  ELSE g.CountryGroup
END
```

The third WHEN could also be written as

```
  WHEN c.TAProfileID = '316' AND c.CurrencyCode <> 'MUR' THEN 'DB International'
```

but `AND c.CurrencyCode <> 'MUR'` is unnecessary: at that point of evaluation `c.CurrencyCode` is not going to be equal to `'MUR'` anyway. It is because evaluation of CASE stops as soon a matched condition is found, and if no match is found when the bare `c.TAProfileID = '316'` is reached, it means the preceding condition failed and, therefore, `c.CurrencyCode` is certainly something else.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I highly appreciate the detailed solution you provided. You made my day! Works beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by something like this

```
CASE 
WHEN [condition1] THEN [Expression] 
WHEN [condition2] THEN [Expression]
WHEN [condition3] THEN [Expression]
WHEN [condition4] THEN [Expression]
ELSE [Expression]
END
```

So in your case would be something like this

```
(CASE WHEN e.TravelAgencyTypeCode = 'DMC' 
 THEN g2.CountryGroup 
 WHEN e.TravelAgencyTypeCode != 'DMC'
 THEN g.CountryGroup
 WHEN c.TAProfileID = '316' AND c.CurrencyCode = 'MUR'
 THEN 'DB Local' ELSE 'DB International') AS 'Market Final'
```

Comment: No need for a nested CASE, just `CASE WHEN condition1 THEN result1 WHEN condition2 THEN result2 ... END`.

Comment: I didn't know that until now. I've learned something nice today. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @CurseStacker Thanks. However, your code is missing the g.countrygroup in the 1st case statement. How do I implement that?

Comment: I added it just now, please take a look. However in your second case, I don't think column = 'some value' would be an acceptable result. It would give Incorrect syntax near '='. error

Comment: @CurseStacker Yep, getting an incorrect syntax error!

Comment: you have to verify your query. are you trying to update that column?

Comment: I guess I'm stuck with this! :-(

Comment: Add the whole SQL Statement to your question. Then let us see why you would need to have a column = 'value' in your case result.

Comment: @CurseStacker Query in its context added. Thanks.